# How do I give an argument a value if the argument is from a different class that I made an instance of in my original class

Tags: python, class

I am trying to figure out how to pass an argument when I create an instance of my class even though the argument comes from a different class.

```
class Car():
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes to describe a car."""
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.manufacturer} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        """Print a statement showing the car's mileage."""
        print(f"This car has {self.odometer_reading} miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """
        Set the odometer reading to the given value.
        Reject the change if it attempts to roll the odometer back.
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
        self.odometer_reading += miles


class Battery():
    """A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car."""

    def __init__(self, battery_size=75):
        """Initialize the batteery's attributes."""
        self.battery_size = battery_size

    def describe_battery(self):
        """Print a statement describing the battery size."""
        print(f"This car has a {self.battery_size}-kWh battery.")

    def get_range(self):
        """Print a statement about the range this battery provides."""
        if self.battery_size == 75:
            range = 260
        elif self.battery_size == 100:
            range = 315

        message = f"This car can go approximately {range}"
        message += " miles on a full charge."
        print(message)

    def upgrade_battery(self):
        """Upgrade the battery if possible."""
        if self.battery_size < 100:
            self.battery_size = 100
            print('Your car battery has been upgraded')
        else:
            print('Your battery is already upgraded')


class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Models aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""
    
    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, year):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(manufacturer, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()
```

When I create an instance of my ElectricCar class, I would like to be able to set 'battery_size' to whatever I want even though it is an argument in the Battery class.
How would I do this?

Comment: `self.battery = Battery(put_value_here)`

Comment: Also, I'd advise against using `range` as the name of a variable, as it will shadow the built-in Python function.

Comment: @MattDMo thank you so much. Should I put battery_size = value or just put the value?

Comment: Either is acceptable. If you think you might be adding more parameters to your `Battery` class in the future, you can add the argument name so it's not ambiguous to anyone reading your code which value is what.